# Coding with emoji in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, emoji, jshint

VSCode giving me errors when using emoji as variables.

[image: prob1]

[image: prob3]

Following is using alphabetical variables.

[image: probl2]

I am trying to code with emoji and get intelisense from emoji. Is it supported yet?

Comment: nothing to do with limitation in VSCODE - it's the **definition** of javascript that is the issue ... why would you want to do such rubbish anyway

Comment: two things, expressive and visual

Comment: Two more: cumbersome and unnecessary. You can't type emoji without copy pasting, complicated codes or [custom keyboards](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U)

Comment: @Bálint, not true at all. all the code editor nowadays come with extensions and I believe emoji is future for programming too. [Emojisense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6BFRY5yrcY&t=8s) . Imagine you can use smiley face to console log in c#, java, js, python. imagine the possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, why would you use short, descriptive names when you can just use a smiley, that doesn't say anything about the variable.

Comment: just giving the examples. some says short and descriptive names , some prefers long. these rules exist coz of human mentality and don't get lines of comments. meaningful emoji can save time and giving bad variables. [food for thought](https://imgur.com/gO8gjYu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://mothereff.in/js-variables, Emoji are not allowed.

From https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

> What is allowed in an identifier name?
>
> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode
>   categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”,
>   “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”,
>   or “Letter number (Nl)”.
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any
>   U+200C zero width non-joiner characters, U+200D zero width joiner
>   characters, and characters in the Unicode categories “Non-spacing mark
>   (Mn)”, “Spacing combining mark (Mc)”, “Decimal digit number (Nd)”, or
>   “Connector punctuation (Pc)”.

Comment: even const somevariables_ = "HappyJack" wont work too.

Comment: @phonemyatt it's not in the 16 bit range, emojis use 2 of those

Comment: @phonemyatt because emoji are not part of both paragraph.